# Lemoon CMS - Unable to use newly created Content Types

Tags: c#, lemoon

In the Lemoon admin I simply am creating a new Content Type called 'test' with just a simple text box titled 'positionTitle' to start with for testing. It gets created just fine, however once I create a new 'test' object in the site i run into problems. I give it a title, some body text, and the postionTitle as it asks - save it and all is well.  However no matter what I change or try I keep receiving this error regarding Content.Title. http://d.pr/i/KVdb

I am using the default 'PageTemplate' as the template for the page so its requesting the Title  obviously, however I have it filled out?!

Where am I going wrong, what am I missing? I have poured through the Lemoon docs with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The PageTemplate is strongly typed to the Page content type as you see in the code-behind of the template. Since you are passing in a Test content type the Content property in the template will be null.

Normally when you create a new content type you will also need to create a new template for rendering it. So what you need to do is create a template for your Test content type. See http://www.lemoon.com/developers/programming/aspnet/templates.

Comment: Thanks Lajjne, I was trying to recycle the existing PageTemplate.  I'll give it a whirl and let you know how I end up!